# Error java.lang.NullPointerException en una clase que obtiene datos para un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Estoy creando un RecyclerView conectado a Firebase, pero en la clase que obtiene los datos de la base de datos, me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Repo {

fun getHobbieData(): LiveData<MutableList<Hobbie>> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Hobbie>>()
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Hobbie").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        val listData = mutableListOf<Hobbie>()
        for (document in result) {
            val nombre = document.getString("Juegos")
            val nombre2 = document.getString("Musica")
            val nombre3 = document.getString("Deportes")
            val hobbie = Hobbie(nombre!!, nombre2!!, nombre3!!)
            listData.add(hobbie)
        }
        mutableData.value = listData
    }
    return  mutableData
}
```

}

> La línea 18 es: val hobbie = Hobbie(nombre!!, nombre2!!, nombre3!!)

Comment: Estás usando `!!`, así que deberías saber qué significa eso, no?? Todavía estoy muy verde en kotlin, la verdad, pero si no me equivoco, `!!` es básicamente un *nullcheck*, es decir, si esa variable está a null, tirará NPE (NullPointerException). Viendo que lo que tienes en esa línea es precisamente un NPE... pues imagino que una de esas 3 variables vale *null*. Por cierto, no es recomendable usar cosas sin saber qué hacen :)

Comment: Aparte del posible NPE, si tuvieras una clase POJO para `Hobbie` no necesitarías obtener y pasar cada parámetro al constructor de `Hobbie`, sino que harías algo así simplemente: `listData.add(document.toObject(Hobbie.class));` Esto simplifica mucho el código, sobre todo en documentos con muchas propiedades.

Comment: deberias chekear bien la nulabilidad

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar `!!` mejor usa `?` en dado caso puedes modificar tu linea de la siguiente manera

```
val hobbie = Hobbie(nombre ?: "", nombre2 ?: "", nombre3 ?: "")
```

De esta manera no rompes tu código.

Aqui la documentación que te puede ayudar a entender: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html